# Unable to add user through django admin page

Tags: django, python-3.x, oracle, django-models

I have been using django-admin page to add user to my application. Recently when I tried to add a new user I started getting TypeError.

The exact error is :-

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/auth/user/add/ Exception Value: 'float' object is not subscriptable Request information

Since I have not changed anything in the code, I am not sure why I am getting this error now. That is why I am at a loss as what to try to solve the issue.

I am attaching the traceback here:-

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  552.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  224.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in add_view
  103.             return self._add_view(request, form_url, extra_context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py" in _add_view
  131.                                                extra_context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
  1509.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  67.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  63.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changeform_view
  1409.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in _changeform_view
  1449.                 self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in save_model
  980.         obj.save()

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  80.         super(AbstractBaseUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1079.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1119.                 return self.connection.ops.fetch_returned_insert_id(cursor)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/oracle/operations.py" in fetch_returned_insert_id
  245.         return int(cursor._insert_id_var.getvalue()[0])
```

It would be very helpful if someone can point me to the proper direction.

Comment: Can you share the code behind that specific view?

Comment: You must share your code and also share your inputs in admin page

Comment: There is no view for this. I am using the django admin for adding users.

Comment: I am using django.contrib.admin and django.contrib.auth.

Comment: what part of the code do you need?  I will share it. I have not coded anything to add a user. Its taken care of by django.